# Webflow Interactions on Wordpress site?

Tags: themes, javascript, hooks

I have a problem, where I can't seem to get Webflow interactions to work on my Wordpress site.

I have read every post about this problem on this forum and elsewhere.

I am not sure the connection between the wf-data and the webflow.js - interactions work when publishing the site out and exporting, but not on Wordpress. Has anyone figured this out yet? I don't use Udesly for my themes; they seem to have figured this issue out.

Any help would be appreciated.

The published site I am talking about is http://highstakes.webflow.io, and the final WordPress site is https://highstakes.thenewshouse.com the preloader works on webflow but not on WordPress.

thx

Answer (score 0):

When moving a webflow designed site over to WordPress you must put the wf-data info in the header of your Wordpress design. The wf-data code will call out specific interactions within your webflow.js. I also call out my CSS in the head of every custom post type template - so if my custom post type is ‘Stories’ - single-stories.php will have a CSS file specific to that new design and then your footer will have a specific webflow.js. I recommend renaming your webflow.js to something specific to your microsite/CPT. This way your new CSS and js will be at the bottom of the cascade and take priority without conflicts.